# For each cell in HTML Table column do X?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

Just looking to see if there's a better way of doing this.

Let's say I have your standard HTML table with a few rows and columns of data. What I would like to do is apply a function to each row or cell which belongs to that column. What I'm trying now is a 3 depth loop and isn't really the best in practice.

```
<table id="myTable"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@example.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.example.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@example.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.example.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@example.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.example.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@example.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.example.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Lets say I wanted to capitalize the Web Site column string or do something neat with it.
I would probably:

```
*select the tbody using dom selector or jquery.
*for loop with each column
   *check if the data is what I want
*for loop for each row
   *do my function to each cell
```

This can be a bit slow and I always try to avoid nested loops when I can.
Is there anyway to maybe use the Dom to treat the column as a container?

```
IE  for (cell x in Column y)
{ doMyfunction(); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can use the .each() function:

```
$('#myTable td').each(function () {
    // action to perform.  Use $(this) for changing each cell
});
```

If you knew you wanted to change only one specific cell in a row, then once you know which cell it is, using the :eq() or :nth-child() selector will allow the specific cell to be manipulated without others in the row doing so.

The code below will manipulate the first cell in the row, as the index for eq() starts at 0.

```
$('#myTable tr td:eq(0)').each(function () {
    // action to perform.  Use $(this) for changing each cell
});
```

The code below will still manipulate the first child, but the index for nth-child() starts at 1

```
$('#myTable tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function () {
    // action to perform.  Use $(this) for changing each cell
});
```

Comment: Very nice function. wasn't even aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to style it its much faster to use css

```
tbody tr td:nth-child(4){font-weight:bold;}
```

as far as i know you can also use that css selector in JQuery

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery

```
$("td", "#myTable tbody").each(function(index, elem){
// do my stuff here
});
```

Comment: depends. If he wants to bind the same function then no. If he wants to do different things based on index then yes.